# cat command is adding extra characters

Tags: android, linux

I have a weird issue where I am reading a binary file with cat. Piping the output is adding extra characters, specifically 0D0D. So I can read a file in a binary editor and it looks like this

```
 ...82 FF B3 C9 0A 97....
```

However, when I cat the output to a text file it mysteriously adds 0D0D like this

```
 ...82 FF B3 C9 0D 0D 0A 97...
```

I am reading a btsnoop_hci.log file generated by an android phone. These are the actual characters in question. I know for a fact that this happens in the middle of a string of characters that make up a Bluetooth link key, so those extra characters should DEFINITELY not be getting added. Does anyone know what is going on, and why cat is adding extra characters??

Comment: If you compare `od -t x1 file` and `cat file | cat | od -t x1` and I'm sure you'll find that no `cat` adds any characters anywhere. Include steps to reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting two carriage return bytes inserted before a line feed byte.  These characters are significant, in different combinations, as line terminators for various operating systems.  (Windows uses the two-byte terminator 0D 0A, Unix and OS X use just 0A, and the original MacOS used just 0D).

It looks, therefore, as if you are getting some kind of text mode processing of your binary data, though why you get that specific processing I couldn't say.  I'm somewhat surprised by your claim that `cat` is performing such munging, but if it's really `cat` and not something else in the pipeline then you probably need to use a different tool.

Comment: You`re right. As mentioned below it is adb issue so I will need to use another method

Answer (score 0):

`cat` is not adding any characters. Try the following:

```
$ adb shell
android$ md5 yourfile
android$ cat yourfile > newfile
android$ md5 newfile
```

Here's an example from my device:

```
shell@hammerhead:/mnt/sdcard $ md5 /system/bin/sh
cf3301e2cf56e5edc88ee20e3899a31e  /system/bin/sh
shell@hammerhead:/mnt/sdcard $ cat /system/bin/sh > newfile
shell@hammerhead:/mnt/sdcard $ md5 newfile
cf3301e2cf56e5edc88ee20e3899a31e  newfile
shell@hammerhead:/mnt/sdcard $
```

You'll notice that the checksums are identical. `cat` did not modify the file in any way.

Now let's try `adb`:

```
$ adb shell cat /system/bin/sh | md5sum
23c023cc5eaca953d4b1733afcdd1097  -
```

The checksum is different.

The problem is not with `cat`. Delete this question and ask a followup about `adb`.